# Bad destination address: foo.bar.local

Tags: networking, local-area-network, traceroute

I don't understand why I get "Bad destination address" in the end.

DNS works:

```
root@pc:~# nslookup foo.bar.local
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   foo.bar.local
Address: 10.100.71.28
```

Traceroute to IP works:

```
root@pc:~# tcptraceroute 10.100.71.28 443
Selected device eth1, address 172.17.6.82, port 34878 for outgoing packets
Tracing some path to 10.100.71.28 on TCP port 443 (https), 30 hops max
 1  172.17.6.254  0.401 ms  0.510 ms  0.402 ms
 2  10.130.4.2  0.941 ms  0.893 ms  0.800 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  10.100.63.11  17.915 ms  20.109 ms  17.054 ms
 6  10.100.71.28 [open]  22.654 ms  17.680 ms  21.081 ms
```

Tcptraceroute to hostname does not work ???

```
root@pc:~# tcptraceroute foo.bar.local 443
Bad destination address: foo.bar.local
```

## Update

Other commands like ping or traceroute can't access foo.bar.local, too.

I get no output from this:

```
getent hosts foo.bar.local
```

Comment: Can other commands (apart from tcptraceroute) use that hostname? Is your system configured (in /etc/nsswitch.conf) to use DNS for hostname resolution? What does `getent hosts foo.bar.local` give?

Comment: @PaulHaldane thank you for the hint to `getent` this way I found the answer which I posted below.

Answer (score 3):

The command from the question reveal that DNS is working and IP networking is working.

What is wrong? :-)

Your operating systems does not directly connect to the DNS like nslookup does.

[Name Service Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) does happen before the operating system asks the DNS if the command `tcptraceroute foo.bar.local` runs.

I fixed it like this:

```
diff -r /var/tmp/etc-saved/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf
11c11
< hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
---
> hosts:          files dns
```